# three.js fails to render scene when using PointerLockControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the problem, that my three.js scene fails to render as soon as i create a PointerLockControls object. I have absoulute no clue what the issue could be.

main.js:

```
const THREE = require("three");
var PointerLockControls = require('three-pointerlock');
//utils
import detect from "./detect"
import dialogs from "./dialogs"
import calc from "./calc"
import {Player} from "./charackters"


//3D stuff
import world from "./world"

//Scene creation
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

var controls = new PointerLockControls(camera);

camera.position.y = -50;
camera.position.z = 40;
camera.rotation.x = calc.rad(90);


//WebGL Renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

world.drawFloor(scene, THREE);
var cGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
var cTexture = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var Cube = new THREE.Mesh(cGeo, cTexture);
scene.add(Cube);


//tick function
var clock = new THREE.Clock(true);
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update(clock.getDelta);
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

if(detect.webgl()){
  animate();
}else{
  dialogs.error("Your browser does not support WebGL. Please install a modern Browser such as Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox to play AlphaWars!", "Warning:")
}
```

if you need any of my additional files please comment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use the PointerLockControls in a wrong way. You should add 
    scene.add( controls.getObject() ); 
after 
    var controls = new PointerLockControls(camera); 
because PointerLockControls object has a attribute pitchObject and you should add it into scene.